# Override Automatic Scroll in Fullpage.js when user uses mouse scroll or keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I'm looking for a little help!

I am using Alvaro Trigo's Fullpage.js for a Wordpress site I'm developing.

On the Homepage, I have each section scrolling automatically every 5000ms.

However, the client has requested this to be overridden if the user decides to navigate each section using the mouse or keyboard. Is this possible? I'm a little unsure how to tackle it.

[Here is the work in progress](http://rankindev.co.uk).

Thank you in advance — Any help will be much appreciated! Please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to listen the mousewheel event and clear the interval you set for your automatic sliding.

[Example online](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/938/)

Something like:

```
addMouseWheelHandler();

function MouseWheelHandler(){
    clearInterval(myIntervalId);
}

function addMouseWheelHandler() {
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener('mousewheel', MouseWheelHandler, false); //IE9, Chrome, Safari, Oper
        document.addEventListener('wheel', MouseWheelHandler, false); //Firefox
    } else {
        document.attachEvent('onmousewheel', MouseWheelHandler); //IE 6/7/8
    }
}
```

`myIntervalId` would be a **global variable** that you have to set when creating your intnerval:

```
var myIntervalId;

//whatever
myIntervalId = setInterval(fuction(){
    $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. The Client has asked if it's possible for if the user has stopped manually scrolling for 5 seconds, to trigger the automatic scroll again. Is this possible? Thank you so much in advance.